# Linked Lists Append To Tail

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an appendToTail function which will add a node to the end of a singly linked list.

I am having trouble in adding a node if the head is NULL(the linked list is empty)

```
class Node {
private:
    Node* next;
    int data;

public:
    Node(int d, Node* n = NULL)
        : data(d)
        , next(n)
    {
    }
    void appendToTail(int);
    //other trivial functions(getters and setters etc. ) defined and
    //declared
};

void Node::appendToTail(int d)
{
    Node* end = new Node(d);

    Node* n = this;

    if (n == NULL)
        n = end;

    else {
        while (n->next != NULL)
            n = n->next;
        n->next = end;
        n->next->next = NULL;
    }

    end = NULL;
    delete end;
}

int main()
{
    Node* n = NULL;
    n->appendToTail(5);
    std::cout << n->getData(); //getData() is a function which
    //retrieves the Data member variable
}
```

I am expecting to get 5 but I am getting an error which appears to be caused because my node remains null.

Comment: `Node * n =NULL; n->appendToTail(5);` you're calling a method on a `NULL` reference, so there's that... You may want to have a `LinkedList` class that has `Node`s, instead of handling `Node`s directly. That will also hide implementation details which are not useful for the users of your class.

Comment: The `end = NULL; delete end;` doesn't do much.

Comment: Can I do it without a creating a new linked list class?

Comment: And so, you are not allowed to call a method on a NULL reference unless its static?

Comment: Eljay, do I not need to free the memory?

Comment: ***do I not need to free the memory?*** You should not free or delete anything in `appendToTail()`. You are adding a node not removing a node.

Comment: ***you are not allowed to call a method on a NULL reference unless its static?*** You are not permitted to dereference a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Now with modern C++ idioms we use smart pointers instead of raw pointers, it gives you the benefit of RAII (Resource acquisition is initialization) mechanism. In addition if you want an elegant solution to your problem you should introduce a List class with which you can express more clearly the concept of an empty list. It would give something like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class List
{
public:
    class Node
    {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
        int data;
    public: 
        Node(int d):next(nullptr),data(d){}
        inline int getData() const {return data;}
        inline std::shared_ptr<Node> getNext() const {return next;}

        friend List;
    };
    List():head(nullptr),tail(nullptr){}

    void appendToTail(int );

    inline std::shared_ptr<Node> getHead() const {return head;}
    inline std::shared_ptr<Node> getTail() const {return tail;}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Node>   head;
    std::shared_ptr<Node>   tail;
};

void List::appendToTail(int d)
{
    auto newTail = std::make_shared<Node>(d);

    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = tail = newTail;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newTail;
        tail = newTail;
    }
}

int main()
{
    List    l;
    l.appendToTail(5);
    std::cout<<l.getHead()->getData();
}
```

But you should definitely prefer `std::list<T>` or `std::vector<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there several errors with your approach. Semantic errors and a logical error with your interpretation of a linked list. Let's start with your initial misunderstanding. You cannot add a new tail to an empty list. Because it is emtpy. Meaning, not yet existing. Only if some object is existing/instantiated you can add a tail. You cannot add something to not existing stuff. So your idea to start with a Node* n = nullptr cannot work logically.

Additionally you are dereferencing a nullptr (major bug). That is also the main problem of your code. Nothing works. You need an instantiated object, before you can call it's member functions.

So before you can populate the list, you need to create/instantiate it initially. So you need to explicitly create the first node in your main function with

```
 Node* n = new Node (5)
```

Then the list is existing and from now on you can add new members with calling appendToTail.

There are more semantic errors in your code which have luckily no side effects.

You must not delete the 'end' variable in your function. You want to keep the newly allocated memory for the new tail. But you introduced an additional sematic error by setting 'end' to nullptr and then call delete. Deleting a nullptr is a noOp and will do nothing. So, although you have a semantic error, this will not cause any trouble.

There is more:

For a pointer to Null you should always use nullptr.

And, your

```
if (n == NULL)
```

is always false. Before that, you assigned this to n. This is never NULL. You can delete the if else. Keep the statements from the else, except the

```
n->next->next = NULL;
```

That's not necessary. The constructor did that already for you. As explained, the next 2 statements should also be elimanted.

Additionally you may want to read a little more on the concept of linked lists.

I hope I could help a little